# Java. Why does my image not appear in my GUI

Tags: java

so I have this class of a Laser. My problem is the laser texture is not showing up. Can you point out where the mistake is, please? I'm having a project to present next week and I'm hitting this problem. I'm most likely not executing it right outside this class. 
The code is doing what it is supposed to do, the image is the problem though.
When I press my UP arrow it is supposed to launch a laser beam to the opposite ship, destroying it, I press my UP key, I don't see any laser beam but the adversary gets destroyed.

```
private class Player1weapon {
        int centerX, centerY;
        boolean isFalling;
        public Image laserp1;
        public ImageIcon icon;


        public Player1weapon() {
            isFalling = false;
            icon = new ImageIcon("resources/laserplayer1.png");
            laserp1 = icon.getImage();
        }

        void updateForNewFrame() {
            if (isFalling) {
                if (centerY > height + 10) {
                    isFalling = false;
                }
                else 
                    if (Math.abs(centerX - player2.centerX - 40) <= 30 && Math.abs(centerY - player2.centerY) <= 21) {
                        player2.isExploding = true;
                        player2.explosionFrameNumber = 1;
                        isFalling = false;
                        player1.score+=10;
                    }
                    else
                        if(player1.isExploding){
                            isFalling = false;
                        }
                        else
                            centerY -= 30;
            }//end if   
        }//end updateForNewFrame()

        void draw(Graphics g) {
            if (!isFalling) {
                centerX = player1.centerX + 37;
                centerY = player1.centerY + 23;
            }
                g.drawImage(laserp1, centerX, centerY - 8, laserp1.getWidth(null), laserp1.getHeight(null),null);
        }//end Draw()

    }//end player1weapon
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the image? I don't see any components of which you are drawing ON.

Comment: @peeskillet The image is doing what it is supposed to do but I can't see it. I do have a paintComponent where I added player1weapon.draw(g);

Comment: How do you know it's doing what it's supposed to do if you can't see it? Maybe you should post your GUI class.

Comment: Maybe your file is in the wrong location. Where is the resource file? I mean in what directory?

Comment: @peeskillet I do know what it is supposed to do because I can see the effect. When I press my UP arrow it is supposed to launch a laser beam to the opposite ship, destroying it, I press my UP key, I don't see any laser beam but the adversary gets destroyed.

Comment: Are you running from an IDE?

Comment: @peeskillet No, I don't think so.

Comment: I mean how are you running your program? from an IDE like netbeans or eclipse? If you are, take a look at my answer. It may just be a problem with your file path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running from an IDE (like eclipse or netbeans), make sure your directories look something like this

```
ProjectRoot
         resources
                laserplayer1.png
         src
```

May be just a problem with your file path.

Comment: You are awesome, should've be "src/resources/laserplayer1.png" instead of "resources/laserplayer1.png". I didn't think of that, thank you.